# Why is the address of an object added to a C++ STL vector different than its original address?

Tags: c++, stl

I've got a very simple method that adds a node to a graph:

```
  template<class T>
  void AdjacencyList<T>::add(const GraphNode<T>& node) {
    _nodes.push_back(node);
  }
```

In another method, I iterate over the `_nodes` vector, looking for the added node by address:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < _nodes.size(); i++) {
  if (&(_nodes[i]) == &node)
    // do something
}
```

However, this does not work, because when I add `node` to the `_nodes` vector, the added member has a different address:

```
Graph::AdjacencyList<int>::add (this=0x8052338, node=...) at ../AdjacencyList.h:42
42      _nodes.push_back(node);
(gdb) p node
$1 = (const Graph::GraphNode<int> &) @0xbffff39c: {value = 123}
(gdb) n
43      }
(gdb) p _nodes[0]
$4 = (Graph::GraphNode<int> &) @0x80522b0: {value = 123}
```

What in the world is going on here? And more importantly, how should I be adding a member to a vector so that I can find it later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's a different object. All standard containers own their objects and all types that you use in standard containers must be copyable.

When you pass an object to `push_back` it is copied into the vector. If you want to be able to find it later your object type must have a concept of equality where you can compare and find equivalent objects. (Either that, or you must remember which location you placed each object in the vector.)

Comment: This makes perfect sense. And now that I think about it, it would be quite silly to have two nodes in a graph with the same value, so I should just define an == operator for my `GraphNode` class that compares values. Thanks for your help, and I'll accept your answer as soon as SO allows. ;)

Comment: I don't think it is silly. You might have different graphd noe holding the same value but with different links in the graphs. Maybe not in you case however.

Comment: @ysdx: Yes, you are quite right, and that was my original intent as well. I'd basically need to assign each node a UUID to handle this, I think. However, I'm fortunate enough in this particular case to not need to support multiple occurrences of the same value--I'm more or less modeling a network topology, where device A cannot appear more than once--at least, I **hope** that's the case. ;)

Answer (score 5):

The object is *copied* into the vector, so the address of the copy stored inside the vector is surely different from the address of the original object since no two distinct objects can have identical addresses.

To find your object later you can either compare it by some other property (one of more of its member variables) or store its index in the vector somewhere. The usual approach is that every object has some "identifier" member variable that is unique at least for all objects stored inside one vector.

Comment: Correct answer, thanks. I'm accepting Charles's answer only because he provided some advice on the "how should I be doing this?" aspect of my question. :)

Comment: @Josh Glover: Sure, feel free to do so.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to push a copy of your object (of type T) into the container, you can use a container of smart pointers of T :

```
 std::vector< std::shared_ptr< Graph::GraphNode<int> > > c;

 std::shared_ptr< Graph::GraphNode<int> > p = std::shared_ptr< Graph::GraphNode<int> >(new Graph::GraphNode<int>(whatever));
 c.push_back(c);
```

With this you can compare the pointer.

You can use auto_ptr, shared_ptr, unique_ptr (or boost smart pointers [2]) depending on your needs.

Boost has pointer containers as well [1].

Also, look how graph are implemented in Boost.Graph [3]. You might want to use a similar approach.

[1] http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html

[2] http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm

[3] http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/graph/doc/table_of_contents.html

Comment: Ah yes, smart pointers. That's a fantastic solution--far better than my idea of UUIDs.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb remember that STL uses copy semantics. So unless the STL container is a collection of pointers, any element added to a STL collection will be *copied*.